# for loop for checking presence of hash table value not iterating

Tags: c++, for-loop, hashtable

I am making a hash table of type vector< vector > which is a string in this case. Inside my function for checking whether a given word is in the hash table, I have a for loop that runs through the collision vector checking if the given word is there. For some reason the for loop is not iterating, b is always == 0. I have checked multiple times what the value of table[index].size() is and it is above zero.

```
        for( int b=0; b < table[index].size(); b++)
        {
            cout<< "b: "<< b << endl;

            if (table[index][b] == object)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code? whats the input? what are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from your for loop in every cases. 
So it does 1 iteration and then exit from the loop. 
The first iteration is b=0